# Can a kanyakubja brahmin and saryupareen brahmin marry? If not, why so?

Tags: marriage, tradition, brahmins

Please tell me can a saryupareen and kanyakubja brahmin marry?

Comment: I think this is a personal advice question.

Comment: Well as far as I know in Hindu marriages the gotra should be different of bride and groom, so as long at that is fine there should not be any problem.

Comment: Of course they 'can' marry in today's times. Probably your question is on, 'should' they marry? That also seems fine as both belong to same divisions/classes, hence their intellectual levels are supposed to be same, if their family lineages were maintained. Both belong to northern Indian belt.